# Is there a way to page through questions without seeing previous questions?

Tags: feature-request, question-lists

On stackoverflow.com, when I click on the questions tab and start paging through all of the questions, many times it will display the same questions that I have seen on the previous page.

I think what is happening is that as new questions come in, they are inserted at the top and all previous questions are pushed down to older pages.  So, when the next page is clicked, then those questions show up again.

It is very annoying to wade through a whole bunch of questions that I just went through.  So, my question:

Is it possible to see questions in time order (from a given point) such that previous questions do not get shown again?

If the answer is no (which I strongly suspect), then it would be helpful if the website could add a new link on the web page which could be called something like "Next Page In Sequence" (and its counterpart - "Previous Page In Sequence") that would display the next page of questions based upon the last question shown on the current page.  Or, perhaps just modify the prev and next page buttons to perform this behaviour by default.  It should not be hard to do this.

A 4-byte unsigned int sequence number could be assigned to each question as it comes in.  The sequence numbers for the first and last questions on a page could be sent and would not have to be displayed.  When the prev or next button is pressed, then that command along with the first and last sequence numbers could be sent back to the webserver which should then use the appropriate sql query to return the next set of questions.

I don't see anything like a suggestion box on this site, so how are suggestions and feature requests submitted?